# Cucumber test passed, but jenkins failed

Tags: jenkins, cucumber

I have a lots of tests on several server. I use Jenkins to manage all of them.
On one server (Slave Windows), when I launch a test in cmd, I got something like :

```
c:/tests/cucumber --tag @dev -p ie
...
1 scenarios (1 passed)
12 steps (12 passed)
0m31.761s
echo %errorlevel%
0
```

No error in the tests, and cucumber seems good.

When jenkins launch exactly the same tests, I get :

```
c:/jenkins_folder/cucumber --tag @dev -p ie
...
1 scenarios (1 passed)
12 steps (12 passed)
0m28.453s
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The test passed, but is marked failed by jenkins.

The command "echo %errorlevel%" is aborted : the job fail before this point.

- The same job played on another slave work.
- Same problem with all profile and all tags.
- Same problem when I replace profile by real value
- I don't use the --strict flag
- Jenkins, plugins : all up-to-date

Code of the windows batch :

```
cd /test8folder
cucumber --tag @dev -p ie
echo %errorlevel%
```

What did I missed ?

Comment: Why are you using `C:/echo`? Windows doesn't come with `C:/echo`. A simple `echo` is a valid batch command line, nothing extra required. Also, you are pasting the result, but could you please paste the actual script in your "Execute Windows Batch command" step?

Comment: Is the failing node the same node you tried the command in cmd on?

Comment: Batch added in the question. (The c:/ is a mistake when I copy the results)
And yes, same node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the configuration.

The fact that you get `Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure` after your cucumber command without actually seeing the `echo %errorlevel%` executed only reaffirms that there was an error in cucumber (more on that later).

**However**, in **Execute Windows Batch Command**, even a command in error would not exit the batch script (unlike Jenkins's default **Execute Shell** implementation). You should be seeing at least some exit code, 0, 1, or anything.

The only time this would happen is if something within your buildstep executed `exit /b [exit_code_num]`. I don't know "cucumber", but if that is in-fact a `cucubmer.bat` and inside there is an `exit /b` statement, this is what's causing it drop out of the buildstep without continuing.

## Solution

You can use **`call cucumber [whateverparams]`** so that even when it quits with `exit /b`, the control will return to the calling process, the **Execute Windows Batch command** script.

Try that first. And you will probably see that your `echo %errorlevel%` will probably return a non-zero value when executed under Jenkins, but at least you will see it now.

Now, as for why it succeeds on command prompt, but fails within Jenkins, there could be a lot of reasons, the most common one being environment variables and paths. We can tackle that later once we actually see the exit code of cucumber. You also said it worked on another node: even more reason to believe this is an environment issue, maybe a non-existent folder...

***Edit:***
The reason that even "successful" test execution exits the calling script is because `exit /b 0` would still quit the calling script, even though cucumber exited with "success" `0`

Comment: cucumber exit code are 0 if all tests passed. Other values are when tests failed, are pending AND flag --strict is used...
The same command with the same parameters in shell (mac or linux) work great. This happen only on one server.

Comment: It can have any number of silent failures, even when tests are fine. The Execute Windows Batch Command wouldn't quit without executing all your statements *including final `echo`*, unless there is an `exit /b` in cucumber batch (did you confirm that it's `cucumber.bat`?). Put the `call` in front of `cucumber` command like I suggested, and at least you will see your final echo execute

Comment: Cucumber is a ruby gem. I'll try your tip monday : I d'ont have access to the server from home.

Comment: Using `call` fix the problem. I don't understand why, I will read the doc about that

Comment: @Fabrice31 I did some quick research and did confirm that this ruby gem uses a `cucumber.bat` file. I couldn't actually get the content of this batch, but like I explained, if it has an `exit /b` (even with `0`) statement, it would exit the whole batch. When you call it from `Execute Windows Batch command` build step directly (which in itself is a batch script) it is considered "in-line", so `exit /b` exits the whole thing, including the build step. Using `call` specifies that it is a separate script, so `exit /b` only exits that script, not the whole build step. Glad it helped you.